# Postfix error 'TLS Library Problem' code 45

Tags: postfix-mta

I've updated the location of certificates that Postfix uses (now served from the nginx directory since they are wildcard) and I'm getting a TLS library error:
`Sep 18 13:37:22 blueberry postfix/smtps/smtpd[15717]: warning: TLS library problem: error:14094415:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 45:`
I have checked the certificate paths in both dovecot and postifx (specifically in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf`, `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and `/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map`, have I missed any?) and they all seem to be correct. The error reads `../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544`, which I assume is some sort of file but I don't remember ever seeing (or touching) it. In fact I do not know what it is relative to and had no luck finding it. I would appreciate any help.

Edit: Should I symlink the certificates into postfix/ssl?

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: I purged postfix & dovecot and made the configuration again from scratch.